# Which table to point out in SELECT statement while joining tables with common columns

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2012

I want to list all columns selected from a join. If a column is present in both tables, say we have 2 such columns: ID (as a key of the join) and Name, should I write:

`SELECT` **t1**.ID, t1.Name `FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID`

or

`SELECT` **t2**.ID, t2.Name `FROM`

or

`SELECT` **ID**, Name `FROM`

or it does not matter at all which table I choose. Of course, in the SELECT statement there will be other columns strictly from t1 or t2 - otherwise the join would not make sense.

Comment: You should not omit table alias, you will have duplicate columns with same name then. I'm usually using column from first (left) table, unless it is outer join and we need this ID, which can be null. It doesn't actually matter with inner joins.

Answer (score 1):

For an `inner join`, it sort of doesn't matter.  For a `left outer join` you would typically want the column from the first table; and for a `right outer join` from the second.  Otherwise, the value could be `NULL`.

I say it "sort of" doesn't matter, but:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Name
SELECT t2.ID, t2.Name
```

could result in slightly different execution plans, if the optimizer decides that it needs to pick up `t1.id` from the data pages -- which it might, if the query were more complicated.  As a general rule, I would stick with referring to as few tables as possible in the `select` because this helps the optimization engine choose the best plan.

Note that some other databases support the ANSI standard `using` clause, which allows you to write:

```
SELECT ID, t1.Name
FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN
     table2 t2
     USING (ID)
```

But SQL Server doesn't (yet) support this.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL SEVER

Below statement will work

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Below statement will also work

```
SELECT * FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

This will result in all the columns from table1 and table2

Below Statement will not work

```
SELECT ID,NAME FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```

Columns are ambiguous, sql server will not know which Table columns to project

Best practice

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Name FROM table1 t1 INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.ID=t2.ID
```